# How Do I know whether my record has been Manually committed using Spring Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I would like to know how commit works when the `AckMode` is set to `MANUAL` in spring kafka.

Below is the property that I have set in `KafkaConfig`
    containerProperties.setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL);

The `listener` code

```
@KafkaListener(id="POC", topics = "TestTopic", group = "TestGroup")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String,KafkaPayload> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        countDownLatch.countDown();     
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}
```

I am doing the `acknowledgement` as per spring kafka documentation, but this would only mean that my message is marked as **sent** but not **consumed** (This is my understanding).

1. In that case, should I call the **`commitSync()`** method. 
   If **yes**, where do I invoke that from, as I need to get a reference to `KafkaConsumer`.
   If No, How does it works internally, Can I track it ?
2. Is there a `commitId` or some value that gets returned ?
   My Idea is to know whether a particular consumer record is consumed or not.
   I would like to store the value for internal tracking purpose.
3. Does kafka internally maintain any state on the consumer record like (**Acknowledged**, **Committed**, **Not Committed**) which can be helpful to categorise.

This would really help me to distinguish how many records are consumed and how many are pending and their states.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer to the first question. Everything rest looks like a story for Apache Kafka directly.

Since we can't perform `commit` from where we would like, but only from the same thread which performs `consumer.poll()`, we store all the commit requests in the internal `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` queue and take a look into that in the main consumer's loop before performing `this.consumer.poll()`.

Even if you use `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`, the real `consumer.commitSync()` is performed on a different thread from your `acknowledgment.acknowledge()`.

OTOH hand the API there in the `Consumer` looks like:

```
public void commitSync(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets);
```

So, there is no any `commitId` hooks to tackle.

I think there is no such a notion in Apache Kafka like `Not Committed` or anything else. The data is always there in the topic log and it isn't removed from there until the particular admin operation or compaction configuration.

I think the `commit offset` feature is fully tied with the `consumer group` purpose and according JavaDocs we have:

```
* This commits offsets to Kafka. The offsets committed using this API will be used on the first fetch after every
* rebalance and also on startup. As such, if you need to store offsets in anything other than Kafka, this API
* should not be used. The committed offset should be the next message your application will consume,
* i.e. lastProcessedMessageOffset + 1.
```

So, when your consumer died, it will restart from the last committed offset for its group. A different group may read the same data but from some other offset. I think that's absolutely why their API doesn't provide any hook to the actual state. There is just no such one!

Comment: Thanks Artem for the detailed response.

So, What I understand from the above answer is that the `consumer.commitSync()` is happening on a different thread when we invoke `acknowledgment.acknowledge()`.

Hence, that ensures the commit is happening. Is it the same behaviour for 'commitAsync()` as well ?

I hope its same for `AckMode.MANUAL`, as I am not using `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`

Comment: Yes, that's true. Any `Consumer` operations happens on the same thread. `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` differs from `MANUAL` only via immediate `consumer.wakeup()` breaking the current poll.